# Windows server 2008 R2(standard) client connection is very slow after connecting above 24 client machines? Is there any client connection limit?

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2008-r2, cpu-usage, tcpip

Windows server 2008 r2 standard is connecting 24 cilent machines after while adding extra machines to server it gets slow. In Windows server 2008 r2 maintaining the mysql database and all other client machines are pointing to mysql database server. In all client machines applications are installed individually.

**Server Specifications:**

OS : Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard.

Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) 5160 3.00GHZ 2.99GHZ(2Processors)

RAM: 64.0GB(32.0GB Usable)

System type: 64-bit operating system

Answer (score 0):

> Windows server 2008 r2 standard is connecting 24 cilent machines

What do you mean with this?

> In Windows server 2008 r2 maintaining the mysql database and all other client 
>   machines are pointing to mysql database server.

So, you are not talking about Windows here, but MySQL Being slow.... so, let's have a look at your machine... OS; Processor, RAM, but NO WORD ABOUT DISCS.

It is likely a combination between non-competent programming and unsuitable hardware is the culprit.

Bad programmed databases eat tons of IO (and good ones still need a lot). So the most important thing on a database server are the discs. Realize that you say nothing about them?

Depending what you do, you may need between 2 and 2000 SAS discs (or more) to satisfy the IO demands - the number of users is irrelevant unless you can specify what they do. Heck, I am loading a similar server (a little smaller) to the max at times with 3 users (and 200 machines pushing data) and that is a sevrver with about a dozen SSD for the database.

So, stop blaming windows - start analyzing where the load is spent and then start looking at your discs and mysql configuration.

Comment: My Disk Space is 2TB . Is there any client connection Limit in windows server 2008 r2? . Mysql.exe tooks high usage(100%) .we analysed slow query log no query executed more than 20 second and we killing sleep connections but cpu usage is 100%. Currently 30 client machine connected into server. we plan to connect 50 more connection. is need any update in server configuration? kindly help us a lot.

Comment: And like most people clueless about databases you think it is about disc SPACE. It is about IOPS. If your disc space of 2tb is on one disc you SUCK at IO - it is a SLOW AND LARGE disc. Typical discs for databases are SMALL (wonder why they still sell 73gb SAS Discs? Exactly). Or - today - people use SSD. If you really use "one 2tb disc" (or a mirror of them) then here is your problem - pathetic disc performance.

Comment: Given demonstrated competence I can advice to hire someone to look over your server and fix also your programming. Yes, it costs money, but there is a limit of what we can do here to replace experience.